# Can I add Wi-Fi adapter to printer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer

I have laser printer (Canon i-Sensys MF3010), although this model is one of the best models but it doesn't have Wi-Fi function, my question that is there any sort of piece that can be attached to the printer to make it print using Wi-Fi?

** A piece such as the ones we connect to normal TVs to make it smart TV. **

Is there a similar piece that can be used with a printer?

Comment: Does it at least have Ethernet, or only USB?

Comment: Print servers are a thing, yes. If they will work with this particular printer, no idea.

Comment: @DanielB what is the piece called and I will make research for it if it can be used or nit for normal printer.

Comment: @user1686 its Ethernet port on the printer but the other end of the cable is USB where it can be connected to the PC

Comment: That doesn't really make sense? Either it's a USB port or it's an Ethernet port. (I've seen APC UPS have custom USB ports that look a bit like Ethernet-but-wider, but I don't think any printers do this?)

Comment: @m7mdabuodeh are you sure it has an ethernet port?  I just looked the model up and it doesnt have it... but there may be more than one version.  Either way, you can get an ethernet to wifi bridge or USB/WiFi print server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not add a Wifi-adapter to this printer.
Your only interface to this multifunction printer [is USB 2.0](https://www.canon-europe.com/business/products/office-printers/multifunction/black-and-white/i-sensys_mf3010/specifications/).
Plugging anything but another machine into this port will only result in frustration.  The printer firmware will not know how to deal with it.

As mentioned in the comments, you could setup a proper "print server".. but for most simple light use, this is overkill.

Here is a possible solution.  You can use any old junky PC to share this printer through it's own network connection.  You can even use one of your primary machines to do it..

The PC does not need to be good.. it just needs to work.  The resources required for printer sharing are very small.

For windows, [here is a link for sharing your printer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-your-network-printer-c9a152b5-59f3-b6f3-c99f-f39e5bf664c3).
For Linux, [here is a link for using CUPS to share your printer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CUPS/Printer_sharing).

The gist of it will be first to get it working on the host PC (just like you probably already have).

Comment: A print server need not be a PC. They (still) exist as embedded devices, off-the-shelve.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I believe this the best solution

Comment: Agreed @DanielB .. of course they do.  I was trying to differentiate between a PC and some other form of print server.  I was trying to say that go could get this done with junk laying around.. :)  Perhaps I failed :^P .. thanks for the comment.